# Is it possible to filter form field according to another field?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to choose only a car_model related to the selected vehicle_brand. Is it possible to do in django? Or need to use JS?

Template rendering Vehicle model objects, that contains vehicle_brand and car_model fields. What did I expect? When selecting a vehicle brand in the form field filter car_model queryset that related to the vehicle brand.

The code example below:

forms.py

```
vehicle_brand = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Бренд', queryset=VehicleBrand.objects.all(),
                                       widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select form-select'}))
car_model = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Модель', queryset=CarModel.objects.all(),
                                   widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select form-select'}))
```

models.py

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    vehicle_brand = models.ForeignKey('VehicleBrand', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_model = models.ForeignKey('CarModel', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class CarModel(models.Model):

    car_brand = models.ForeignKey(VehicleBrand, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    year_production = models.DateField()
```

template:

```
<div class="mb-3">
                    {{ form.vehicle_brand|label_with_classes:"form-label" }}
                    {{ form.vehicle_brand }}
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    {{ form.car_model|label_with_classes:"form-label" }}
                    {{ form.car_model }}
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your models and explain the relation between them?

Comment: you mean dynamic dropdown?

Comment: @rahul.m added to the description

Comment: @HemalPatel Yes, dynamic. As an onchage trigger in JS but in Django.

Comment: aware of Ajax calls?

Comment: @HemalPatel yes, but I'm interested if it is possible to do with django core utils

Comment: I never used another approach but found this. Take a look this might help. [django-smart-selection](https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects). Edit: it uses Ajax queries anyways.